# Chat application to send location with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, location, chat, android-gps

How can send my location coordinates with firebase in android ,i see a chat applications that use firebase but i don't understand how to put code of my Gps  in it that can send coordinates in real time like the messages

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to create a model class that should look something your like this:

```
public class MapModel {
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public MapModel() {}

    public MapModel(String latitude, String longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {this.latitude = latitude;}
    public String getLatitude() {return latitude;}

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {this.longitude = longitude;}
    public String getLongitude() {return longitude;}
}
```

Than you need to create a variable in your `Activity` like this:

```
private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 123;
```

Override your `onActivityResult` and it should look like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
                if (place != null){
                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                    MapModel mapModel = new MapModel(latLng.latitude + "", latLng.longitude + "");
                    databaseReference.push().setValue(mapModel);
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

To send the location, create a method like this:

```
private void locationPlacesIntent(){
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you managed to send location?